# Cannot specify link libraries for target which is not built by this project - but I really want to

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies, buildconfiguration, build-target

A project of mine depends on CUDA, and also on another library, call it libfoo, which itself depends on CUDA. Now, in the CMakeLists.txt of libfoo, we find:

```
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if(CUDAToolkit_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 11.1)
    _CUDAToolkit_find_and_add_import_lib(nvptxcompiler_static)
    target_link_libraries(CUDA::nvptxcompiler_static INTERFACE Threads::Threads) 
endif()
```

Now,

1. I can't change the CMake of libfoo and
2. The `target_link_libraries` command is valid and legitimate, to the best of my understanding.

However, when I write:

```
FetchContent_Declare(foo
    # bunch of args here
    OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
    )
find_package(foo REQUIRED)
```

in my project, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at build/_deps/foo-src/CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "CUDA::nvptxcompiler_static" which
  is not built by this project.
```

How can I get CMake to be willing to run this command, even though it doesn't like it?

As a second-best alternative - can I get CMake to skip the command in this case rather than fail?

Comment: "That command is valid and legitimate." - Please, provide **more details** on that aspect. Documentation of [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command describes that the first argument "must have been created by a command such as add_executable() or add_library() and must not be an ALIAS target.". So, whether the target `CUDA::nvptxcompiler_static` actually **exists**? Is that target ALIAS or not?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Yes, it actually exists; but I mis-spoke: NVIDIA didn't forget the dependency, they forgot to define this target. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Oh, so `libfoo` project actually uses a function `_CUDAToolkit_find_and_add_import_lib`, which is **internal** for [FindCUDAToolkit.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindCUDAToolkit.cmake) script. But that function doesn't always create an IMPORTED target. How exactly have you checked that the target is actually created? Have you added `if(TARGET CUDA::nvptxcompiler_static)` to the libfoo code? Or how?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I use that target elsewhere, so I know it's created. Note the code snippet _is_ in the libfoo code - I said so in the question text.

Comment: "I use that target elsewhere" is quite **unreliable** evidence, since your project may use separate call to `find_package(CUDAToolkit)` and obtain the target from it. Also, as you probably well know, an IMPORTED target has a **limited visibility**. For debugging purposes it is much reliable to add corresponding check to the libfoo code. Since you use FetchContent, this modification could be achieved e.g. by cloning libfoo locally, making modifications and pointing the local directory in `FetchContent_Declare` call.

Comment: "Note the code snippet is in the libfoo code" - That doesn't mean that given code is *correct*. I would say that given code is not quite correct, since it uses the target `CUDA::nvptxcompiler_static` without checking that the target actually exists/created.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Ok, you're saying I should be more careful and not assume existence. But in practice, the target is created and does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a change of behavior which occured with CMake v3.25.3 ;  with v3.24.2 and earlier it does not occur, and I can configure my project fine with libfoo.

Have filed [this bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25528) with KitWare. Advice is welcome...